# Where can I find resources to learn about the internals of Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

I want to dive into Mac OS X, but don't know any good sources to learn from.

I found this book: [Mac OS X Internals](http://www.amazon.de/Mac-OS-Internals-Amit-Singh/dp/0321278542/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1328303841&sr=8-1), but it's a bit old, and from the recessions it  discusses the PowerPC, and not the Intel versions of Mac OS X.

Where can I find good books or websites?

And I don't mean the Apple Developer Forum, I want to know everything about from the kernel up to the Mac OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you've already found it, how about something like [The Mac Hackers Handbook](http://www.amazon.de/Mac-Hackers-Handbook-Charles-Miller/dp/0470395362/ref=pd_sim_eb_2/277-7949191-0253606)? It seems to have been published in 2009 and references Leopard in the description, so may also be a little out of date, but from the [reviews](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mac-Hackers-Handbook-Charlie-Miller/dp/0470395362) seems to have a reasonable amount of information about security and OS X internals. May be a bit left field for what you want though...?

Or for something newer (due to be publishe June 2012) how about [Mac OS X and iOS Internals](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1118057651/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_1?pf_rd_p=103612307&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0321278542&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1WGJPS6X47T2AJS8Z7GJ)?